# MySQL Memory Grows Over Time

Tags: mysql, memory

I've got a server running a LAMP stack with 1GB RAM that is maxed out on RAM usage.  What I'm observing is that directly after a reboot, it drops to 25% usage, and then slowly climbs over time so that by the end of the day, it's sitting at 100%.  When it peaks out, mysql is using 940MB according to TOP.

I've tried lowering many of the settings to reduce caching and buffer sizes (not ideal I know, but just trying to get the memory usage under control first - then things can be redialed in)

Current /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
# Basic settings
user = mysql
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Security settings
local-infile = 0
symbolic-links = 0

# Memory and cache settings
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 4M
thread_cache_size = 4
table_cache = 256
tmp_table_size = 8M
max_heap_table_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 1M
key_buffer_size = 1M
max_connections = 10
wait_timeout = 300

# Innodb settings
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 2

[mysqld_safe]
# Basic safe settings
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

MySQLTuner.pl Output:

```
# ./mysqltuner.pl

>>  MySQLTuner 1.2.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
>>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
>>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.30
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 51K (Tables: 109)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 15M (Tables: 387)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 387

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2d 15h 14m 29s (1M q [4.411 qps], 71K conn, TX: 2B, RX: 78M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 62% / 38%
[--] Total buffers: 31.0M global + 3.6M per thread (10 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 67.2M (6% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/1M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 80% (8/10)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 1.0M/450.0K
[!!] Key buffer hit rate: 90.7% (935 cached / 87 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 82.7% (201K cached / 243K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 11934
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 15K sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 9% (17K on disk / 194K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (20 created / 71K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 6% (256 open / 3K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 9% (102/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (81K immediate / 81K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 15.7M/16.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
> Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
> Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
> Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
> query_cache_size (> 4M)
> table_cache (> 256)
```

What I don't understand is that MySQLTuner says "Maximum possible memory usage: 67.2M (6% of installed RAM)", yet as indicated earlier, MySQL is using 940MB of RAM.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

** **EDIT** **

If I stop the mysql process, memory usage dips a little bit but is still pretty maxed out.

Before:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024       1019          4          0          0          3
-/+ buffers/cache:       1016          7
Swap:         1024         79        944
```

After:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        998         25          0          0          4
-/+ buffers/cache:        993         30
Swap:         1024         53        970
```

** **EDIT** **

I tried stopping processes in order of what's taking up the most memory and it seems like something just isn't releasing.  Here's what I did:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:            5164 kB
Cached:            14128 kB
Active:            37104 kB
Inactive:          53436 kB
Active(anon):      29876 kB
Inactive(anon):    46536 kB
Active(file):       7228 kB
Inactive(file):     6900 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:         968756 kB
Dirty:                12 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         76412 kB
Shmem:              4776 kB
Slab:             952804 kB
SReclaimable:     941112 kB
SUnreclaim:        11692 kB

#top -a
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1240 mysql     20   0  872m  33m 7476 S  0.7  3.3  22:59.35 mysqld
12662 root      20   0  234m  26m 3136 S  0.0  2.6   0:04.72 spamd
12663 popuser   20   0  234m  24m  964 S  0.0  2.4   0:00.02 spamd
15299 site1     20   0  285m  14m 8816 S  2.7  1.4   0:00.28 php-cgi
15302 site2     20   0  285m  12m 7800 S  0.0  1.3   0:00.10 php-cgi
  782 root      20   0  436m  11m  10m S  0.0  1.1   0:10.66 httpd
15277 root      20   0  102m 4928 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.05 sshd
14342 apache    20   0  436m 3924 2048 S  0.0  0.4   0:03.31 httpd
14272 apache    20   0  436m 3920 2048 S  0.0  0.4   0:03.79 httpd
  793 nginx     20   0 46432 2568 1684 S  0.3  0.2   5:38.31 nginx
14830 postfix   20   0 51716 2332 1772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 pickup
15281 root      20   0  105m 2064 1532 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 bash
  754 postfix   20   0 51916 2028 1932 S  0.0  0.2   0:35.17 qmgr
 3977 postfix   20   0 51716 1992 1896 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 tlsmgr
  743 root      20   0 51656 1936 1836 S  0.0  0.2   0:43.71 master
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
21335 apache    20   0  318m 1356  612 S  0.0  0.1   0:20.91 httpd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.20 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15301 root      20   0 14896 1248 1008 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 top
  837 root      20   0 11304  756  752 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 mysqld_safe
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
  634 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  644 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  652 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 couriertcpd
  661 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd

***killed mysql***

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:           35296 kB
Cached:            13820 kB
Active:            24436 kB
Inactive:          36712 kB
Active(anon):      16984 kB
Inactive(anon):    30344 kB
Active(file):       7452 kB
Inactive(file):     6368 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:        1001512 kB
Dirty:                16 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         47328 kB
Shmem:              4776 kB
Slab:             952068 kB
SReclaimable:     941180 kB
SUnreclaim:        10888 kB

#top -a
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12662 root      20   0  234m  25m 3136 S  0.0  2.5   0:04.73 spamd
12663 popuser   20   0  234m  23m  964 S  0.0  2.3   0:00.02 spamd
15322 site1     20   0  285m  14m 8804 S  0.0  1.4   0:00.23 php-cgi
15324 site2     20   0  285m  12m 7800 S  0.0  1.3   0:00.10 php-cgi
  782 root      20   0  436m  11m  10m S  0.0  1.1   0:10.66 httpd
15277 root      20   0  102m 4916 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.05 sshd
14342 apache    20   0  436m 3924 2048 S  0.0  0.4   0:03.33 httpd
14272 apache    20   0  436m 3920 2048 S  0.0  0.4   0:03.82 httpd
  793 nginx     20   0 46432 2568 1684 S  0.0  0.2   5:38.32 nginx
14830 postfix   20   0 51716 2332 1772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 pickup
  754 postfix   20   0 51916 2028 1932 S  0.0  0.2   0:35.19 qmgr
 3977 postfix   20   0 51716 1992 1896 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 tlsmgr
15281 root      20   0  105m 1948 1552 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 bash
  743 root      20   0 51656 1936 1836 S  0.0  0.2   0:43.72 master
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
21335 apache    20   0  318m 1356  612 S  0.0  0.1   0:20.92 httpd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.20 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15362 root      20   0 14896 1244 1008 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
  634 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  644 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  652 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 couriertcpd
  661 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd

***killed httpd ***

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:           58476 kB
Cached:            13932 kB
Active:            11752 kB
Inactive:          30812 kB
Active(anon):       4180 kB
Inactive(anon):    24452 kB
Active(file):       7572 kB
Inactive(file):     6360 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:        1013752 kB
Dirty:                24 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         28632 kB
Shmem:              2568 kB
Slab:             947400 kB
SReclaimable:     941172 kB
SUnreclaim:         6228 kB

#top -a
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12662 root      20   0  234m  25m 3136 S  0.0  2.5   0:04.73 spamd
12663 popuser   20   0  234m  23m  964 S  0.0  2.3   0:00.02 spamd
15277 root      20   0  102m 4916 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.06 sshd
  793 nginx     20   0 46432 2580 1688 S  0.0  0.2   5:38.35 nginx
14830 postfix   20   0 51716 2332 1772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 pickup
15281 root      20   0  105m 2060 1552 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.03 bash
  754 postfix   20   0 51916 2028 1932 S  0.0  0.2   0:35.19 qmgr
 3977 postfix   20   0 51716 1992 1896 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 tlsmgr
  743 root      20   0 51656 1936 1836 S  0.0  0.2   0:43.72 master
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.20 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15380 root      20   0 14892 1120  900 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
  634 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  644 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  652 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 couriertcpd
  661 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd

***killed spamd***

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:           83548 kB
Cached:            13948 kB
Active:            10668 kB
Inactive:           7720 kB
Active(anon):       3068 kB
Inactive(anon):     1372 kB
Active(file):       7600 kB
Inactive(file):     6348 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:        1039244 kB
Dirty:                 8 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          4440 kB
Shmem:              2568 kB
Slab:             946580 kB
SReclaimable:     941176 kB
SUnreclaim:         5404 kB

#top -a
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15277 root      20   0  102m 4916 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.08 sshd
  793 nginx     20   0 46432 2580 1688 S  0.0  0.2   5:38.36 nginx
14830 postfix   20   0 51716 2332 1772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 pickup
15281 root      20   0  105m 2064 1552 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.04 bash
  754 postfix   20   0 51916 2028 1932 S  0.0  0.2   0:35.19 qmgr
 3977 postfix   20   0 51716 1992 1896 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 tlsmgr
  743 root      20   0 51656 1936 1836 S  0.0  0.2   0:43.73 master
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.20 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15383 root      20   0 14892 1120  900 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
  634 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  644 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  652 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 couriertcpd
  661 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd


***killed nginx***

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:           84848 kB
Cached:            14000 kB
Active:            10100 kB
Inactive:           7396 kB
Active(anon):       2460 kB
Inactive(anon):     1036 kB
Active(file):       7640 kB
Inactive(file):     6360 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:        1041180 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          3496 kB
Shmem:              2564 kB
Slab:             946196 kB
SReclaimable:     941164 kB
SUnreclaim:         5032 kB

#top -a
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15277 root      20   0  102m 4916 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.09 sshd
14830 postfix   20   0 51716 2332 1772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 pickup
15281 root      20   0  105m 2064 1552 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.04 bash
  754 postfix   20   0 51916 2028 1932 S  0.0  0.2   0:35.20 qmgr
 3977 postfix   20   0 51716 1992 1896 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 tlsmgr
  743 root      20   0 51656 1936 1836 S  0.0  0.2   0:43.74 master
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.20 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15392 root      20   0 14892 1120  900 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
  634 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  644 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  652 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 couriertcpd


***killed postfix***

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:           86168 kB
Cached:            14524 kB
Active:             9448 kB
Inactive:           7624 kB
Active(anon):       1628 kB
Inactive(anon):      920 kB
Active(file):       7820 kB
Inactive(file):     6704 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:        1042612 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          2548 kB
Shmem:              2564 kB
Slab:             945276 kB
SReclaimable:     941152 kB
SUnreclaim:         4124 kB

#top -a
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15277 root      20   0  102m 4916 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.09 sshd
15281 root      20   0  105m 2064 1552 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.06 bash
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.20 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15409 root      20   0 14892 1112  900 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
  634 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  644 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  652 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 couriertcpd
  661 root      20   0 13972  560  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd


***killed courier***

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1048576 kB
MemFree:           87032 kB
Cached:            14504 kB
Active:             9456 kB
Inactive:           7564 kB
Active(anon):       1596 kB
Inactive(anon):      920 kB
Active(file):       7860 kB
Inactive(file):     6644 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048576 kB
SwapFree:        1043556 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          2516 kB
Shmem:              2564 kB
Slab:             944472 kB
SReclaimable:     941128 kB
SUnreclaim:         3344 kB

#top -a
top - 10:06:59 up 4 days, 11 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  17 total,   1 running,  16 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,   961660k used,    86916k free,        0k buffers
Swap:  1048576k total,     5020k used,  1043556k free,    14488k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15277 root      20   0  102m 4916 3828 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.10 sshd
15281 root      20   0  105m 2064 1552 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.06 bash
  589 sw-cp-se  20   0 61704 1784 1780 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.19 sw-cp-serverd
  757 postfix   20   0  394m 1340 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.21 psa-pc-remote
  476 root      20   0  179m 1316 1056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0 19232 1256 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 init
15436 root      20   0 14896 1220 1008 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
 1408 root      20   0  114m  728  644 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.17 crond
  608 root      20   0 22096  696  692 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  600 root      20   0 64120  612  508 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sshd
 1462 root      20   0  4064  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 1463 root      20   0  4064  508  504 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
  616 root      20   0 64308  312  308 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  134 root      16  -4 10640  296  292 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
  617 root      20   0 64308   48   44 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/106004
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/106004
```

Comment: Semi-random things to try... does doing `FLUSH TABLES` change anything?  How about if the server is started with `thread_cache_size` = 0?

Comment: The information written to the MySQL error log immediately after you do `sudo killall -HUP mysqld` might also provide some kind of useful insight since it gives some stats about memory utilization (and leaves the server running, btw).

Comment: FLUSH TABLES dropped the usage about 5% temporarily.  I started the server with thread_cache_size=0 and still had the same issue, although it crept up MUCH more slowly.

Comment: You say usage dips a little after you stop mysqld but it's a vary small drop.  Memory down from 1016 to 993 and swap down from 79 to 53... so it seems impossible that MySQL was using very much memory before you stopped it and something else is using quite a lot, assuming mysqld did indeed stop.  Did you happen to notice how much `top` said it was using before you stopped it, and verify that it actually did stop?

Comment: I just added more info.  It seems that something isn't releasing memory?

Answer (score 4):

The formulas that tuning scripts like mysqltuner use to estimate potential memory usage are bunk. These  posts explain why and give some examples of things that could be causing the memory usage pattern you're seeing:

[How much memory can MySQL use in the worst case?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/02/12/how-much-memory-can-mysql-use-in-the-worst-case/)

[MySQL Server Memory Usage](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/17/mysql-server-memory-usage/)

This post talks about isolating the problem by running tests:

[Troubleshooting MySQL Memory Usage](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/21/troubleshooting-mysql-memory-usage/)

The simplest explanation is that there is a query with large memory overhead, which should be identifiable by running the query in isolation and observing its impact on memory usage.

As the post says, memory usage issues are one of the more annoying problems to have in MySQL, and the lack of instrumentation features that other RDBMS have really shows here and makes this type of problem difficult to diagnose.

Comment: +1 for accurate application of the word "bunk."  Also, there's good info at [How MySQL Uses Memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-use.html).

Comment: Thanks - I ran through the troubleshooting article, and I'm more confused than ever  :/  The memory usage slowly grows over time until it maxes out (after a reboot).  What's really odd is if I stop the mysqld process, the memory usage will go from 100% down to 95%, but it's not getting released...  Only a reboot clears it all out.  I don't know how I can isolate a specific query as the server runs many of them.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what's using your memory if it's 95% used when MySQL is stopped? Does `free -m` show it's in buffers and cache?

Comment: I just added the output to the main question

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case it looks like something other than MySQL is using all the memory. `cat /proc/meminfo` and `top -a` should show what that is. Another possibility might be that your MySQL installation isn't controlled by the init script at /etc/init.d/mysqld?

Comment: Hi James, I just added more info on this - any ideas?

Comment: According to the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`, most of the memory is used by slab, which  is a kernel cache. MySQL is only using a small amount of memory. Most of the slab usage is listed as `SReclaimable`, meaning that this memory is available for other processes if needed. Most likely this is just caching of filesystem metadata (inodes); `slabtop -s c` should show you. Are you seeing an actual problem, or just worried that memory usage is high?

Comment: When grabbing data from mysql, we were getting memory errors for larger arrays of items.  it only happens after the server has been running for awhile.  Any ideas on releasing this memory?  When I run "slabtop -s c", I get "fopen /proc/slabinfo: No such file or directory"

Comment: That error sounds like an OS bug, but isn't something I'm familiar with, sorry. The point with the slab memory marked reclaimable is that it should still be usable by other programs if they need it; the kernel is just caching for efficiency. If the top and /proc/meminfo output are taken from a time when you were having a problem, then I don't know what was wrong other than that it wasn't MySQL using all the memory on the server. If they weren't taken from a time when you were having a problem, then I'd wager they look a bit different when you are having memory allocation problems.